# how can i find duplicate values and delete them (with trigger) after insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, duplicates, sql-delete

how can i write a trigger that find duplicate values and deleting them .

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[deleteduplicate] 
ON [dbo].[products]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    declare @productname nvarchar(20),@prodcutid int
    select productname=@productname,productid=@prodcutid from inserted
    if exists (select productname=@productname from products)
    begin
        delete products
        where @productname=productname
    end

END
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Why not stop the insertion of duplicate values in the first place with a unique constraint or index?

Comment: That trigger you have added is flawed; it assumes that an insert only contains one row. An insert can contain 1 or more rows, and your triggers need to be written to reflect that.

Comment: Also, the trigger would delete not just the rows that already existed, but the row you just inserted too (assuming the Insert contained one row).

Answer (score 5):

You don't delete duplicate values in a trigger.  You ensure database integrity using constraint.  In this case, a `unique` constraint.  That is defined using a unique constraint or index:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_col1_col2_col3 on (col1, col2, col3);
```

Of course, this will not work on a table that already has data and has duplicates.  So, you remove them once:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number(*) over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by co1l) as cnt
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: Topicstarter. keep in mind that if `co1l` is non unique (non primary/unique key) the wrong record(s) can be deleted or the wrong one saved..Because the non deterministic ("random") nature or `ORDER BY` where values are equal.. Also ideally you want atleast to add one column which has a primary or unique key to the `ORDER BY` to get that deterministic ("fixed") order

Comment: where seqnum > 1   ?   Are you sure?

Comment: That's the normal way to delete duplicates, @Esperento57 .

Comment: i think he want use cnt variable and not seqnum